# How to add TimePicker time to BroadCast Receiver pending intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a reminder app I'm developing and everything works like its supposed to except the time the user is notified. I use a Time Picker to choose the time, but do not know how to add the user-set time to the pending intent. I have researched the android docs as well as other sites with similar searches, but to no avail. Any ideas?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    int mHour;
    int mMinute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void setAlarm(View view) {
        TimePicker picker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Toast toast = Toast (text, picker);
        toast.show(); 

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBoadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 1234, intent, 0);

        Calendar AlarmCal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        AlarmCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        AlarmCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
        AlarmCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, /*No Idea what to put here*/, pendingintent);

        OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mHour = hourOfDay;
                mMinute = minute;

            }
        };
    }

    private Toast Toast(EditText text, TimePicker picker) {
        return Toast.makeText(this, "Reminder set for " + picker.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":" 
        + picker.getCurrentMinute() + " with message " + "'" + text.getText().toString() + "'", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    public void exitApp(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**AlarmBoadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmBoadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);
  }
}
```

**Manifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.reminder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" >
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.reminder.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="AlarmBoadcastReceiver" >

        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

With what is posted above the phone vibrates every time the Set Time button is pressed, not when the Time Picker time is set for. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should note, is that the AlarmManager has two modes for firing off an Alarm at a set time.

- The set() will fire off the Alarm at the given time. You will note as of API 19, Alarms defined using the set() method may be batched and therefore may not be fired at the exact time:

> Note: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is
>   treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time,
>   but may be deferred and delivered some time later.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

- The setExact() method was added as of API 19 and guarantees that the Alarm will be fired off at the exact given time.

The times passed in are defined as per the first parameter of the set() or setExact() methods. You have chosen RTC_WAKEUP, you need to define the wakeup time in milliseconds UTC time (as given by the System.currentTimeMillis() method).

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP

The easiest way of getting this time is by calling:

```
AlarmCal.getTimeInMillis()
```

Just a small note, if the given time is in the past, then the Alarm will instantly fire. This is why your Alarm was being triggered the moment you set it.

Additional note from the documentation:

> Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can
>   optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but
>   will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.

Comment: I added the AlarmCal.getTimeInMIllis() and set the time for 3 minutes in the future. The phone vibrated about 10 seconds after the button was pressed.

Comment: To test that you are passing in the correct value, try pass through (System.currentTimeMillis() + 1 * 60 * 1000) which should be one minute into the future.

Comment: Also note from the documentation: Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.

Comment: Just tested (System.currentTimeMillis() + 1 * 60 * 1000) and it worked properly. So what might be the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing your problem, but you could output the difference between the AlarmCal.getTimeInMillis() and System.currentTimeMillis() methods and see how that value changes with  the values you set? Also, in the code you've defined above, mTimeSetListener isn't used?

Comment: My apologies, I just accepted your answer. Thank you very much! I removed the mTimeSetListener, I believe that was from another thing I tried. I also tried outputting the differences, and there is about a two second difference between the two. Maybe its the line in the MainActivity class: AlarmCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());?

Comment: You're very welcome :) Right, so if that two second difference is consistent regardless of the input time you select, it would indicate that your mHour and mMinute variables are never modified from their default 0 value.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Forgive my ignorance, but how would I make it so the mHour and mMinute variables are changed? Would it be in the block where the Calendar is set?

Comment: Given your question I would suggest you spend some time looking at some Java lessons, but good on you for trying. You want to hook up the Listener you defined to your TimePicker by calling picker.setOnTimeChangedListener(mTimeSetListener). All the best with your project! :)